# Can second-hand marijuana smoke cause somebody to fail a drug test?

Tags: recreational-drugs, marijuana

In 1988, Olympic athlete, Ross Rebagliati, failed a drug test for marijuana.

The [Bleacher Report](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1607611-ross-rebagliati-controversial-snowboarder-opens-weed-dispenary-embraces-past) explained:

> Rebagliati claimed, and still claims, that the positive was triggered by second-hand smoke he unwittingly inhaled at a going-away party. He copped to past marijuana usage, but said he stopped smoking 10 months before the Games began.

Is it plausible to ingest enough marijuana through second-hand smoke to fail a drug test?

Comment: Possible notable claim for this - snowboarder Ross Rebagliati failed a drugs test for cannabis and claimed it was due to 2nd-hand smoke. http://bleacherreport.com/articles/1607611-ross-rebagliati-controversial-snowboarder-opens-weed-dispenary-embraces-past

Comment: While your question is probably a good one, the rules here are such that you might need to show notability of the claim by referencing it to somewhere other than a personal opinion. I'd include tom77's link to meet that requirement.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about illegal activity.

Comment: Hmm - maybe I shouldn't have cast that close vote, as the OP claims they aren't going to be doing anything illegal themselves.

Comment: It is not illegal in many places in the world. The place is not stated.

Comment: @istepaniuk The place is stated. It says its in Denver, which is in Colorado where marijuana is legal.

Comment: This is not a personal advice site. I significantly edited the question to stick to Rebagliati's claims, and to scrub the hypothetical about the OP's personal life.